# barchart "grouped by" option doesnt distinct categories properly

Tags: bar-chart, plotly

I have a barchart to display the number of action on a keyboard for a time interval of 10 seconds. Without using "group by" function, I have the expected result:

http://postimg.org/image/by1vzottr/

However, I wanted to improve it by using group by function. Therefore, I categorized my Y value. EG: if Y < 10, cat = 0; if Y < 20, cat = 1 etc. But when using "Group by" option, I have this result:

http://postimg.org/image/fcx8e8j4x/

My goal is to have the first graph display, but with the colour corresponding to the categories.

Comment: Can you post your code please, so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am directly building the chart in plot.ly. My initial plot.ly sheet looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/j7wztunfb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is Étienne from plotly.

In brief, plotly doesn't understand that your x-axis values are in fact times, not mere categories.

Currently, the plotly grid understands datetime formats listed [here](https://plot.ly/date-format-and-time-series/#entering-dates-and-times-in-plotly%E2%80%99s-grid).

Once in one of the supported formats, a grid like https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2603 turns into a plot like https://plot.ly/~etpinard/2607/_0-1-2/ .

I hope this helps.